# Venn diagram or matrix box question. Overlapping set problem.

Tags: linear-algebra

The 7th grade French and Spanish classes each have 15 students in them, and there are five students in the 7th grade taking both languages. If everyone in the 7th grade is in at least one of the two language classes, how many students are taking just one of the two classes?

So I don't know how to draw a Venn diagram... but imagine 2 circles with a small overlap in the middle. The left portion of this Venn diagram is A, the overlap portion is B, and the portion on the right is C.

How do we setup algebra to solve?

We want to find regions A and C.
B = 5
A + B = 15
B + C = 15

Therefore A and C each are 10 so the answer is 20?

A friend of mine is saying that the equations should be:
B = 5
A - B = 15
C - B = 15

Who's right and why? He's saying that we need to subtract B because otherwise we'd be counting the region twice.

Answer (score 0):

In your picture, let's say that the left circle (composed of parts A and B) represents the students taking French and the right circle (parts B and C) corresponds to the students taking Spanish. The number of students taking French is 15. That can be expressed as your $A+B$. The number of students taking Spanish is likewise 15, which is your $B+C$. Finally, you know that 5 students are taking both, so $B=5$. You want to compute the total $A+C$.

You have three equations:
$$\begin{align}
A+B&=15\\
B+C&=15\\
B&=5
\end{align}$$
Add the first two equations:
$$
A+2B+C=30
$$
subtract twice the third equation from this:
$$
A+C=20
$$
You're right; your friend is wrong. The total number of students taking French is $A+B$. We don't run into double-counting $B$ here, although we would have to adjust for it if we had been asked to find the *total* number of students in the seventh grade. In that case we'd want $A+B+C$ which is 25. You might want to look at the [inclusion-exclusion principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).

Comment: I think I only need to know A + C

Comment: @Jwan622. Drat. You're right. I'll fix it.

Comment: many thanks Rick!